# MapKeyEnumerated to String

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-5.x

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "entity_identifier")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKey(name = "type")
@Column(name = "identifier")
val identifiers: MutableMap<IdentifierType, String> = mutableMapOf()
```

throws this

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: java.lang.String
```

the tables are simple

```
create table entity(
    id serial primary key
);
create table entity_identifier(
    entity_id bigint references entity ( id ),
    identifier text,
    type text,
);
```

is there a way I can make this `Map` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I need to use `@MapKeyColumn`, I don't know why

```
@ElementCollection( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="entity_identifier")
@MapKeyColumn(name="type")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "identifier")
val identifiers: MutableMap<IdentifierType, String> = mutableMapOf()
```